# Is there an easy way to solve an "almost quadratic" equation?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I have an equation of the form:

$ax^{k_1} + bx^{k_2} + cx^{k_3} + dx^{k_4} + e = 0$

where

$a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are arbitrary real numbers; $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive reals in the range of 1.92...2.08; $k_3$ and $k_4$ are positive reals in the range of 0.96...1.04.

It is known that there exist two real $x$ that satisfy the equation. We are interested in finding both. At least one of these $x$ is positive.

**Is there a relatively lightweight way to solve this equation numerically?**

By "relatively lightweight" I mean that an operation as complex as a logarithm should be taken no more than just a handful of times (say, 20 or so).

Right now the best idea I have is to assume that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are strictly equal to 2 and $k_3$ and $k_4$ are strictly equal to 1. This way the equation becomes quadratic and I can solve it by taking just a single square root, but I wonder if I can have more precise solution.

**Would the task be easier if we can get another set(s) of coefficients {$a,b,c,d,k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$} having approximately the same solution?**

Comment: Yes, and it is called Newton method. First you localize the roots by plugging certain values, then run Newton method, until you find the roots.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I usually run Newton simultaneously with bijection (to have some sanity check at each step), which doubles the running time in the case when everything is nice but eliminates problems in ugly scenarios. However localizing the roots may present some problem in the case when crossings are near touches, so that part may require some thought unless some a priori information is known from other considerations.

Comment: I made up an algorithm in 1984 which worked for an arbitrary number of variables, however, all coefficients and exponents were positive, except that the free term was on the other side of the equation (i.e. this one was negative after all :) ). I believe that my algorithm was much faster than Newton's algorithm in the given case - I didn't do a solid error analysis (it was just a 1-page handwritten memo which I've written for my colleagues at a company).

Comment: @fedja: "bijection" --> bisection?

Comment: If you just plot your function with any software to see where the roots are, and then run the Newton method if you need high accuracy. Since you know the number of roots in advance, no problems can arise.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko 1) Yes, of course :-) 2) My understanding of the problem was that you need a quick and reliable solver for dynamic inputs of $a,\dots, k_4$ under the assumption that there are always exactly $2$ roots for some external reason, in which case "plotting with any software" is totally out of question.

Comment: I suppose they mean mean positive roots (since the exponents are not integers). Their number can be estimated by Decartes rule in any case.